# How to thank people who correct me on my incorrect pronunciation?

Tags: sentence-construction, politeness

How to thank to people who correct me on my incorrect pronunciation?

1. Thank you for the correction.
2. Thank you for your attention

Someone told me in the past that it's not right to say correcting in this context. I would like to see your opinion about that and shape a constant comment.

Comment: Make it an adjective and you can probably avoid any negative connotations of the verb and the noun, or at least dilute them:  thanks for giving me the correct pronunciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem in thanking someone for 'correcting' the pronunciation. After all, that someone *did* correct your pronunciation.

> Thank you for correcting *my pronunciation*

Of course, this is *one of the ways.* There could be a couple more.

Answer (score 2):

Since that person is correcting you (providing you constructive criticism[?] one way or another presumably) and you want to thank that person by stating particularly the point why you are grateful, you can say:

> **"Thank you** (/I'm grateful) **for your correction** (/criticism [you may use 'criticism' if the one who corrects you has the notion of constructive criticism]). **I learn (so much) from it**."

Maulik V is right, there are so many ways.

Also, a plain and simple **"Thank you"**, if sincerely stated, beats everything else. Appreciation should be given in a sincere fashion anyway.

Comment: One warning... most people assume that "criticism" is a very negative thing, so I, personally, wouldn't recommend using it in this situation.

Comment: oh, I'd edit to follow your advice. Many thanks, @Catija!